# How to prove $\{0,1\}^*$ equals $\{1\}^* (\{0\}\{0\}^*\{1\}\{1\}^*)^*\{0\}^*$

Tags: combinatorics, formal-languages, regular-language

Consider the set of all binary strings which is $\{0, 1\}^∗$
Now I want to prove the following:

(A) Prove that $\{0,1\}^* = \{1\}^* (\{0\}\{0\}^*\{1\}\{1\}^*)^*\{0\}^*$
(B) Prove that the elements of $\{0,1\}^*$ are uniquely created on the right-hand side of this equality.

Here is what I have done so far.

Each element $ \alpha \in \{0,1\}^*$ has $k$ occurrences of $0$ for some $k$. Thus we can write
$\alpha = b_1 0 b_2 0 ... b_k 0 b_{k+1}$
, where $b_i$ are consisting of 1's. So $b_i \in \{1\}^*$. Hence we can see that

$\{0,1\}^* =  \{1\}^* (\{0\}\{1\}^*)^*$

Now I want to continue from this expression.

However, I dont have a clue how to do so with the same argument. I also tried proving inclusions, but wasn't successful.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of *?

Comment: @jimjim ...  Suppose $A$ is a set of symbols.  Then $A^*$ is the set of all strings (of finite length $\ge 0$) made from the symbols of $A$.

Comment: @jimjim for example $\{1\}^*$, the $*$  so means $0$ or more occurences of the character $''1''$, so matches $" ", "1", "11" $and so on.

Comment: Your regexp just splits the sequence uniquely into alternating blocks of 0 and blocks of 1.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: There was a "silly mistake" in my answer (B) Part , @DrTokus1998 , which I have rectified now.

Comment: @prem thank you for your clear answer! I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(A)** It is true that $X = \{0,1\}^* = \{1\}^* (\{0\}\{0\}^*\{1\}\{1\}^*)^* \{0\}^* = Y$
Proving that is by showing that **(A1)** every element in $Y$ is in $X$ & **(A2)** every element in $X$ is in $Y$
I will elaborate the Proof in Excruciating Detail (a term I came across here at MSE !) though that is not really necessary when OP gets experience.

**(A1)** Consider a String $S$ in $Y$ : It is made of Digits $0$ & $1$
Naturally , $S$ must occur in $X$ which is the Set of all Binary Strings.

**(A2)** We can check that Null String , $0$ , $1$ , $01$ , $10$ will all match the Pattern & will occur $Y$.
Consider a longer String $S$ in $X$ which might or might not start with $1$ &  might or might not end with $0$
$S=1^*(0Z_1Z_2Z_3 \cdots Z_n1)0^*$
We can match the Initial Block of $1$ Digits to $\{1\}^*$ , where that Block might be Null String.
We can then match the terminal Block of $0$ Digits to $\{0\}^*$ , where that Block might be Null String.
We have then taken $S=1^*(0Z_1Z_2Z_3 \cdots Z_n1)0^*$ to removed the Initial Block & terminal Block to leave the Central Block $(0Z_1Z_2Z_3 \cdots Z_n1)$

Because the Central Block starts with $0$ & terminates with $1$ , we can see that every $0$ Sequence must have a following $1$ Sequence.
We can match every such Sequence against $(\{0\}\{0\}^*\{1\}\{1\}^*)$
which we can repeat the necessary number of times.
Hence every String in $X$ occurs in $Y$

$X=Y$

**(B)** Uniqueness is true here.
Consider $1010101010101010$ : The $0$ Digits in the Central Block can match either against $\{0\}$ or against $\{0\}\{0\}^*$
Likewise , the $1$ Digits in the Central Block can match either against $\{1\}$ or against $\{1\}\{1\}^*$

Provided we have the ${D}^+$ Operation to indicate matching $1$ or more Digits ( which is Equivalent to the ${D}{D}^*$ Operation ) , we can write it like this :
$X = \{0,1\}^* = \{1\}^* (\{0\}^+\{1\}^+)^* \{0\}^* = Y$
Now , we match :
a Block of all $1$ Digits (which might be Empty)
followed by (Zero or more) alternating Blocks of all $0$ Digits and all $1$ Digits
terminated by a Block of all $0$ Digits (which might be Empty)

This is unique.